How to register a custom codec for Media Player?
I've successfully registered an audio codec (x64,x86) for Media Foundation and third-party apps to use. MF can load an MP4 which contains audio compressed with it.
However, the default Windows 11 Media Player won't. As I see, my DLL is not even loaded, which means that Media Player plays the file without MF.
With further testing in my own apps, I saw that the file is able to be played with Media Session (as described here).
So, what is Media Player using to play files, and how do I register the codec to be visible to it (like Microsoft's HEVC implementation in the store, for example)? I suspect it's using some WinUI-based control (MediaPlayerElement?) which looks for codec registrations somewhere that I don't know yet.

"So, what's the MP using to play files and how do I register the codec to be visible to it" - Probably DirectShow - which has a reputation for being particualrly painful to use let alone build on.

DirectShow ?? I really doubt it's that old. I 'm talking about the default player. If it was really DirectShow it wouldn't be playing H265 etc.

I don''t know what the "Default player" is - what with the coming-and-going of MSN Music, Zune, Groove Music, Groove Video, Windows Media Center (rip), and that re-created Media Player that looked a bit Zune-ish - and some other Windows Store-based apps that came-and-went, etc. On my Win10 22H2 machine I still have "Windows Media Player" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe") which I guess might be the default for some things? If so, then  yes: that's a DirectShow-based program.

Well I'm sure nobody would think I would refer to that wmplayer.exe. I'm talking about the default Windows Store Media Player. I'm looking for a programming advice, not suggestion what to use to play files. This is 2024 and my potential users will certainly not use winamp or VLC or whatever except the default.

I took-apart the current Windows Store app for Windows Media Player (the one you liniked-to) and disassembled it - (turns out it's the old Zune Music app from years ago, back-from-the-dead, so yes: it's very-much based on Media Foundation-based, so DirectShow likely is a red-herring here. As for your codec registration: I think the real reason is because it's a sandboxed app that can't just load arbitrary codec/MF libs from-disk, even if they are registered.

Then how it loads hevc when downloaded from the store? I can publish the codec to the store all right but there is no documentation anywhere.

AFAIR this legacy WMP indeed had some additional extensibility mechanism, besides regular DirectShow and WMF codec registration. I remember there was a good post about this on MSDN Forums but it was ages ago. Some additional registry keys with codec implementation references. It is a bit unexpected that its Media Foundation rendering path can't pick your codec up, maybe there is a reason why it falls back to DirectShow and/or legacy WM API. Maybe there is also a chance that you could improve your decoder to keep WMP using WMF, but maybe it does not like your custom codec in the MP4 packaging.

So ~99.9% of all executable code in the app's package is all contained in Microsoft.Media.Player.dll (while Microsoft.Media.Player.exe is a tiiiiny 29KB stub). Interestingly it contains a plaintext listing of all of the precompiled binaries that were statically-linked together - there's no obvious sign of any DirectShow dependencies - while the other files have PE Imports to MFPLAT.dll and the like.

It couldn't be DirectShow, it wouldn't be playing anything nowadays. It's linked to WinRT/WinUI binaries, so mfplat.dll might be used indirectly.

Legacy WMP had two code paths, WMF and fallback DirectShow code path. If it was pure WMF based app, you would be able to see WMF-like behavior and you are seeing something different.
